# ExtJS XML fields working in Chrome but not IE or FF

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, firefox, extjs

I have an ExtJs grid that is rendering in Chrome but not the other browsers. I think it may be the way my fields are defined, are there any additional options needed for other browsers?

Error in IE:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

...return nodupIEXml(cs)}d=++key;**cs[0]._nodup=d;**..

**Code**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var doc;
            var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
            if(isIE == true){        //IE
                doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                doc.async = "false";
                doc.loadXML(xml);
                addLinks(doc);
            } else {                             //Mozilla
                doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
                addLinks(doc);
            }
            var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.XmlStore', {
                autoload: true,
                data: doc,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'xml',
                        record: 'content'
                    }
                },
                fields: [
                    'Title',
                    'Description',
                    'Modified'
                ]
            });
});
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com) with you XML data so we can see what is going on with your grid?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes added fiddle. You can see how it only works in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing, Chrome tends to be a little more lenient with query selectors than other browsers.

For example a tag like `<foo:bar>` queried by `xml.getElementsByTagName('bar');`
Chrome would return 1 result and Firefox fox would return 0.

ExtJS has a specific config for the `XMLReader` called `namespace` to deal with this issue specifically (see: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Xml.html#cfg-namespace).

All you have to do is add `namespace: 'd'` to your XML Reader and it will work. Also, for the same reason your `addLinks` function won't work, so `data.getElementsByTagName` must be replaced with `data.querySelectorAll`.

I updated your fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v